# Is a regular tetrahedron the most optimal equilateral triangle based pyramid and if so how would you prove it?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

If one is to find the minimum surface area to enclose a given volume for this type of pyramid, would they arrive at a tetrahedron?

Comment: This seems very likely due to symmetry. I will attempt to think of a proof.

Comment: indeed, just trying to wonder about that process as well

Comment: This could lead you to a conclusive proof: let $A$ be the base triangle. It has a mid point $M$. Let $L$ be the lead line perpendicular to $A$ through $M$. Let $P$ be an arbitrary fourth point to complete your pyramid. There's a line $\lambda$ through $P$ orthogonal to $L$, which intersects $L$ in $X$. One can 'slide' $P$ over this line; prove that the optimal volume-area ratio is achieved when $P$ coincides with $X$. Now let $X$ slide over $L$; prove that the optimal volume-area ratio is achieved when you have a tetrahedron.

Comment: i am having trouble undestanding that lol, perhaps you could use calculus? partial derivatives?

Comment: My geometric argument should lead you to one-dimensional functions on the lines $\lambda$ and $L$ for which you can use the derivative to find the maximum. Trying to solve it analytically wholesale, with a point $P = (x,y,z)$ and a volume/area ratio function with three variables is *possible* , but is going to get very ugly very quickly.

Comment: how would i use λ and L with respect to one dimensional function with your argument

Comment: All right, so you have your base triangle $A, B, C$. Assume the mid point is the origin, and the perpendicular $L$ is the z-axis. Let $P = (x,y,z)$ be the arbitrary fourth point. The line perpendicular to the z-axis through $P$ is $\lambda: (t \cdot x, t \cdot y, z)$. Proceed to calculate the volume and area of the pyramid consisting of $A, B, C$ and $ (t \cdot x, t \cdot y, z)$ and their ratio; $t$ is the only variable, so you can derive to $t$ to find the point where the ratio is maximal. This should be the point where $t = 0$ i.e. $(0,0,z)$.

Comment: If I knew 3D functions better i'd know what your talking but my understanding on that is limited (yikes). How would you approach this with highschool partial derivatives. You stated that would get nasty fast, however I did a proof on rectangle pyramids and how a square is the optimal rectangle based pyramid. How would those principles be applied here?

Comment: Thanks for outlining what your knowledge base is - that's always helpful. What I outlined is upper-grade high school level analytic geometry. The problem here is that unlike with rectangle-based pyramids, the formulae for area and volume of these kind of pyramids are ugly - if you then have to take their ratio *and* derive it, you end up with a lot of work. I'll try to see if I can remove more geometric aspects from my proof, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: thank you, yea once you get past those formulas, its quite satisfying to see things work in your favor

Comment: @AhmedAnwer: *Any* triangle-based pyramid is a tetrahedron. ("Tetrahedron" simply means "four faces".) So, to be clear: you're asking whether the *regular* tetrahedron (all faces equilateral) minimizes surface area for a given volume. Correct?

Comment: correct, im sorry for not making that clarification

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the base pyramid, and assume the area of $T$ is $B$. Assume the midpoint of $T$ is the origin. Let $P = (x,y,z)$ be the fourth point of the pyramid. Then the volume of the pyramid is $\frac{z \cdot B}{3}$. So planes of the form $z = C$ describe pyramids with equal volume. We now try to find the optimal position of $P$ in such a plane.

If the area of $T$ is $B$, then its base points can be chosen as $(\alpha, 0, 0)$, $(-\frac{\alpha}{2}, -\frac{\alpha \sqrt{3}}{2}, 0)$ and $(-\frac{\alpha}{2}, \frac{\alpha \sqrt{3}}{2}, 0)$ where $\alpha = \frac{2 \sqrt{B}}{\sqrt{3 \sqrt{3}}}.$ It's up to you to calculate the area of the pyramid in function of $x$ and $y$, for a given $z$ and $B$. The desired result is that $(x,y) = 0$. This implies that the optimal pyramids are those whose fourth point lies straight above the midpoint; proving that the tetrahedron is optimal can then be done considering only those kind of pyramids.

Comment: wait a minute, do we have the wrong idea here? Lol, im assuming that the pyramid is a right pyramid so the fourth point is above the mid point of the base. Its just that i want to prove that all faces must be equal for an optimal tetrahedron, if that is the case

Comment: The assumption of a right pyramid is not present in your question, nor in your earlier comments. Don't keep moving the goal posts by adding new assumptions.

Comment: yes i specified after. my apologies